# How to exec command to do sed

Tags: go

I have the following snippet that is not working. Compiles but does not do what it is supposed to. Executing the same command on bash works. Why?

```
hash:="4ab32de"
cmd = "sed -i -e 's/clt_[0-9a-z]*/clt_"+hash+"/g' /tmp/test.env"
    parts = strings.Fields(cmd)
    for _, part :=range parts {
        fmt.Printf("\n%s",part)
    }

    head = parts[0]
    out, err = exec.Command(head,parts[1:]...).Output()
    fmt.Printf("\nnew cmd is %s\n",cmd)
    fmt.Printf("out:%s",string(out))
```

The output of parts is perfect, like this

```
sed
-i
-e
's/clt_[0-9a-z]*/clt_4ab32de/g'
/tmp/test.env
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `exec` package doesn't use the shell, so take out all quotes (and escapes).  In your case, remove the single quotes.

Comment: It worked, but I am still trying to understand why it worked. Any more info may help me understand it conceptually

Comment: @curiousengineer Well, when you issue a command like `sed -i 's/old/new/' file.txt` in the shell, first the shell gets to process the arguments, one step of which includes quote removal. What sed gets to see is just `-i s/old/new file.txt`. I you use quote in Go's `exec.Command()`, sed gets to see `-i 's/old/new' file.txt`, i.e., a command that contains literal single quotes. That's like issuing this in the shell: `sed -i "'s/old/new'" file.txt`.

Comment: @curiousengineer If you're interested, try running a few commands with `set -x` in Bash, and it'll show you what actually gets executed after quote removal & co.

Comment: @curiousengineer -- Benjamin W. explained it well above.